# KeyError: 'False: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index' in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, read.csv

the order is "Ask the user to enter the name of the object for which he wants to receive data and the names of the filters,
data in which you need (it is possible to introduce several filters)."

here is my data:

```
|Object |   HJD 24... |    Filter | Magnitude|
|-------|-------------|-----------|----------|
|SU_Hor | 55896.30476 |    B      |14.877    |
SU_Hor    55896.27438     Ic      13.885
SU_Hor    55896.27349      B      14.809
SU_Hor    55896.27397      V      14.434
SU_Hor    55896.40882     Ic      14.033
SU_Hor    55896.40829      V      14.540
SU_Hor    55896.40770      B      14.941
SU_Hor    55896.34973     Ic      13.958
SU_Hor    55896.34943      V      14.494
SU_Hor    55896.34906      B      14.861
SU_Hor    55896.30542     Ic      13.912
SU_Hor    55896.30512      v      14.440
SU_Hor    55897.38547      V      14.536
SU_Hor    55897.28281      B      14.882
SU_Hor    55897.28317      V      14.428
SU_Hor    55897.28347     Ic      13.927
RZ_Lyr    27359.3030       V      10.630
RZ_Lyr    27684.4510       V      10.610
RZ_Lyr    27685.4780       V      10.580
RZ_Lyr    27701.3150       V      10.700
RZ Lyr    27934.4560       V      10.660
RZ Lyr    27955.4100       V      10.570
rzlyr     30604.2000       V      11.030
RZ_Lyr    55314.5695       B      12.047
RZ_Lyr    55314.5724       B      12.036
RZ_Lyr    55314.5900       B      12.042
RZ_Lyr    55314.6105       B      12.045
RZ_Lyr    55314.6163       B      12.027
RZ_Lyr    55342.3509       B      12.057
RZLyr     55342.3557       B      12.058
RZ_Lyr    55342.3606       B      12.052
RZ_Lyr    55342.3654       B      12.058
```

this is my code:

```
def searchByfilter():
    filter = input('Enter filter to show data \n')
    df = pd.read_csv('Python_2ndLab.csv')
    print(df.loc[df.filter == filter, :])

print('Enter 1 to search by object name')
print('Enter 2 to search by filter')

src = (input('Enter here: '))

if src == '1':
    searchByObject()
elif src == '2':
    searchByfilter()
else:
    print('Sorry, invalid input')
```

I'm trying to solve but still didn't work and I got an error:

```
Enter 2 to search by filter
Enter here: 2
Enter filter to show data 
B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\PycharmProjects\2nd Lab\main.py", line 78, in <module>
    searchByfilter()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\PycharmProjects\2nd Lab\main.py", line 64, in searchByfilter
    print(df.loc[df.filter == filter, :])
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1067, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1247, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 967, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1311, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_key(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1118, in _validate_key
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: 'False: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'
```

I expected to receive the data from all of the "B" filter when I enter "B"

Comment: Do not use `filter` as a variable name, it is a built-in method.

Comment: After replacing the csv reading with mockup data `df=pd.DataFrame([["SU_Hor",55896.27438,"Ic",13.885],["SU_Hor",55896.27349,"B",14.809],["SU_Hor",55896.27397,"V",14.434],["SU_Hor",55896.40882,"Ic",14.033]],columns=["Object","HJD","Filter","Magnitude"])`, and fixing the upper case in the next line, `print(df.loc[df.Filter == filter, :])`, searching for `B`, `V`, or `Ic` all work for me.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` is a method of dataframe. Replace `df.filter` with `df['filter']`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html

Comment: still get an error 'KeyError: 'filter''

Comment: @ZulyaniR Sorry, it is `Filter`, not `filter`. `df['Filter']`.

Comment: now it's error being  'KeyError: 'Filter' hehhe, I really don't know what's happening here...